# How to act as another wallet when using Truffle exec scripts?

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract

I am writing a seed to add data on the smart contract after I deploy it.
I'm using ropsten network, setted up like this in `truffle-config`:

```
ropsten: {
      provider: function () {
        return new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, INFURA_KEY)
      },
      network_id: 3,
      gas: 8000000      //make sure this gas allocation isn't over 8M, which is the max
    }
```

After deploying I want to call my script with `truffle exec scriptName.js`.
In my script I basically need to do two things:
1) Add a brand (which saves the address of another wallet)
2) Call another function acting as the brand I added above. This function can be called only by the brand address.

I am able to add the brand, but I am unable to call the second function because its still called by the owner of the smart contract and not by the brand.

Here is my code:

```
const contract = artifacts.require('contract');
const brandAddress = '0x73aCAEf54005FE8499Ff1159A244617C123F1a53'

module.exports = function (done) {
    console.log("Getting deployed version of the contract...")

    contract.deployed().then(async (instance) => {
         console.log('Adding first Brand...')
         await instance.addBrandAddress(brandAddress);
         console.log('Brand address added: '+ brandAddress)

        //from now on act as the brand
        console.log('Creating first Token...')
        let tokenOne = [
            '1576827018',
            true,
            '43.782988;11.282723',
            '',
            'B2529234802149001329150000E20030',
            '',
            '',
            'Test data'
        ]
        await instance.createToken(tokenOne, {from: brandAddress})
        console.log('First token created: ', tokenOne)
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Seed finished.')
        done();
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        done();
    })
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error: Unknown address - unable to sign transaction for this address: "0x73aCAEf54005FE8499Ff1159A244617C123F1a53"    at PromiEvent (/home/dan/.nvm/versions/node/v13.7.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/promievent.js:9:1)
    at TruffleContract.createToken (/home/dan/.nvm/versions/node/v13.7.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/execute.js:169:1)
    at /var/www/html/initialContractSeed.js:26:24
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  hijackedStack: 'Error: Unknown address - unable to sign transaction for this address: "0x970355374fa0eab7ab02ca56e611144cc2e8fdf0"\n' +
    '    at /var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js:397:1\n' +
    '    at cb (/var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js:441:1)\n' +
    '    at h.cb [as getAccounts] (/var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/src/index.js:99:1)\n' +
    '    at h.getAccounts [as validateSender] (/var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js:438:1)\n' +
    '    at h.validateSender [as validateTransaction] (/var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js:395:1)\n' +
    '    at validateTransaction (/var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js:112:1)\n' +
    '    at apply (/var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/async/waterfall.js:16:1)\n' +
    '    at nextTask (/var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/async/waterfall.js:26:1)\n' +
    '    at h.waterfall [as handleRequest] (/var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js:111:1)\n' +
    '    at handleRequest (/var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:119:1)\n' +
    '    at l.next [as _handleAsync] (/var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:106:1)\n' +
    '    at Timeout._handleAsync [as _onTimeout] (/var/www/html/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:90:1)\n' +
    '    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)\n' +
    '    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)'
}
```

Instead of `from: brandAddress` I tried to use the private key of the address (so `from: brandAddressPK`) but that one still didn't worked.

Maybe I somehow could do it by using web3.js, but I need to send a tuple as a parameter and last thing I remember about web3.js is that wasn't possible (so I switched to ethers.js).

EDIT: What I did to resolve this was to create a js script (without using truffle). By using ethers.js first I create a provider with the private key of the owner, then when I need to act as a brand I create a new provider with the private key of the brand.

It wasn't what I wanted but it works good and do the job.

Comment: You need to unlock this address on the node that you're communicating with (which is not possible with Infura as far as I'm aware of).

Comment: You could expose multiple addresses with the truffle-hdwallet-provider
 like this: `new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, INFURA_KEY, 0, 2)` and then use the second address from the mnemonic as brand address.

Comment: I tried it but still didn't succeed.
What I did to resolve this was to create a js script (without using truffle). By using ethers.js first I create a provider with the private key of the owner, then when I need to act as a brand I create a new provider with the private key of the brand. 

It works very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to solve using a custom HDWallet provider.

HDWallet provider accepts an array of private keys instead of a mnemonic.

```
const contract = artifacts.require('contract');
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

const OWNER_ADDR = '0x1234...';  // Ethereum address
const OWNER_PKEY = 'ABCD...';    // Private key (without 0x at the beginning)
const BRAND_ADDR = '0x4433...';  // Ethereum address
const BRAND_PKEY = 'B1C1...';    // Private key

module.exports = async function (done) {
  const provider = new HDWalletProvider([
      OWNER_PKEY,
      BRAND_PKEY,
    ],
    'http://localhost:8545',
    0,  // start at position 0
    2,  // and use 2 private keys
  );

  contract.setProvider(provider);

  const instance = await contract.deployed();

  // To call a method as owner
  await instance.onwerOnlyMethod({ from: OWNER_ADDR });

  // To call a method as brand
  await instance.brandOnlyMethod({ from: BRAND_ADDR });

  done();
};
```